# How to get work Internationalization module with l function?

Tags: navigation, i18n-l10n

I am using Internationalization module to translate content. 
How to get work this module with l function?

for example, when I create programatically link to content:

```
l(t('About us'), 'node/22');
```

I would like to achieve, that path 'node/22' will change when I switch website to another language. With Internationalization module, each translation of node creates another node, so I need to change paths in links on website.

For this time, 
I can create just if-else condition:

```
<?php
if ($language->language == 'en')
$output = l(t('About us'), 'node/22');
elseif (($language->language == 'de') 
$output = l(t('About us'), 'node/23');
?>
```

IS it possible to use l function in that way, that I don't need to write else-if condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no easy way to do this, but you can do something like this:

```
$nid = 22;
$node = node_load($nid);
if ($node) {
  $translations = translation_node_get_translations($node->tnid);
  $nid = isset($translations[$language->language]) ? $translations[$language->language]->nid : $nid;
}
```

Or use the Entity translation module, which relies on the ability of fields to have values in multiple languages and then the node id doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
l(t('About us'), t('node/22'));
```

and translate node/22 to node/23, but this maybe wrong it's just an idea.